# SharePoint 2010 - Child content types doesn't update

Tags: 2010, content-type, inheritance

Hello I added new field to content type programatically and it updated nicely on test environment, but when I pushed update on main environment the inheriting list content type was not updated even though inheriting option is added to field. Later I tried to remove field by script and re-add it, but it didn't helped. My code:

```
$ctype = $web.ContentTypes[$ctypeName]
if($ctype)
{
    $field = $web.fields.getfield($fieldName)
    $field.PushChangesToLists = $true
    $field.Update($true)
    if($ctype.Fields[$fieldName]){  
        $ctype.FieldLinks.Delete($ctype.Fields[$fieldName].Id)                                  
        $ctype.Update($true)
    }
    $link = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink $field
    $ctype.FieldLinks.Add($link)
    $ctype.Update($true) 
}
```

P.S.: for some reasons code doesn't enter if block where field links are deleted too

Comment: Hey Vilius, I've been struggeling with a similar case. Could you tell me if the base content type was task in your case?